# How do I create collisions on all sides of a rectangle?

Tags: python, pygame

How do I create a collision for all 4 sides of a rectangle? Example: If player runs into the left side, cannot move right anymore. If it falls on top of the rectangle, it stops falling, etc.

Comment: FYI: Looking for examples or any tips/resources I can use to learn this. Thanks!

Comment: Usually, on stackoverflow, you are supposed to show what you've tried and we can help you with that. This kind of questions is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [PyGame Rects](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html). Specifically, look at pygame.Rect.colliderect.

Bellow I've pasted the code to a very bare bones game that I believe outlines what you are looking for.

```python
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

BLACK, WHITE, GREY = (0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255), (100, 100, 100)

block_x, block_y = 25, 175
speed_x, speed_y = 0, 0


run = 1
while run:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = 0
        if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if e.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                speed_x = -5
                speed_y = 0
            if e.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                speed_x = 5
                speed_y = 0
            if e.key == pygame.K_UP:
                speed_x = 0
                speed_y = -5
            if e.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                speed_x = 0
                speed_y = 5

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    block_x += speed_x
    block_y += speed_y

    blockOne_rect = pygame.Rect(block_x, block_y, 50, 50)
    blockTwo_rect = pygame.Rect(600, 175, 50, 50)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, blockOne_rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREY, blockTwo_rect)

    if blockOne_rect.colliderect(blockTwo_rect):
        speed_x = 0
        speed_y = 0


    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason I can still move around inside the other block :/